# Why do these URL segments result in 404s?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, url-routing

Our tester is a master of fuzz testing.

He has discovered that putting certain values into URL segments in our web API always seems to result in a 404, but I cannot work out why. Here are some examples:

- `.,#';][=->`    => 404
- `<~@:}{+_)`     => 404
- `+` => 404
- `.,#` => 404
- `.#,` => routes correctly

So for example, a route that normally looks like

`http://api.mythingy.com/one/two/three`

If you change one of the segments to one of the 'bad strings' above:

`http://api.mythingy.com/one/.,#/three`

Always gives a 404.

I can't see anything resembling escape sequences in there. I do see some dodgy values (such as `<`, but the '404' behaviour seems to take precedence over the 'bad request' behaviour.

Can anyone suggest why this happens?

**Edit:** using the debugger tells me that the application itself isn't hit (i.e. a breakpoint in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest() does not get hit). So presumably this is occurring in IIS.

Comment: A hash is reserved in a URL, separates the (local) fragment identifier, from the remainder of the URL; they should not be sent to the server but used locally by the client. Hardly a surprise that sending them gives a client error. Summary: fuzz testing or not URLs need to be valid URLs to get sensible results.

Comment: Thank you. Any thoughts on `<~@:}{+_)`?

Comment: Without checking the applicable RFC, not immediately. In the end your tester needs to do that him/herself.

Answer (score 0):

why it should return a 400 bad request ? 
404  is the correct answer for requesting a not existing route.

.#, will work because # is the special  identifier for fragemts. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

Comment: ASP.NET by default rejects input containing `<` characters (and a bunch of others) because they may indicate a script injection attack.